# Windows 7 hangs at CLASSPNP.sys after installing a second Xeon processor

Tags: windows-7, drivers, reboot

I have a server in a secure location and do not have installation media or procedures. I'm using this server to play video and audio over the network. The video was pretty choppy and the processor was maxed out so I installed another processor, only issue is that the system constantly reboots after displaying "Starting Windows". It never actually displays the glowing out-of-focus windows logo. It just displays Starting Windows, then black screen, reboot. When I try to boot in to safe mode, the server hangs at CLASSPNP.sys and then reboots automatically.

1. I tried using a Windows recovery disc to repair the boot. Windows recovery could not find any issues.
2. I removed the second processor, windows boots without any issues.
3. I swapped processors, windows boots without any issues.
4. I moved the processor from slot 1 to slot 2, windows boots without any issues.
5. I swapped out the entire motherboard, all of the same occurs.
6. All of the CMOS settings are tested and work fine on other systems with two processors and all the same hardware.

Can anyone help?

Hardware:

- SuperMicro X7DA8 MB
- Intel Xeon E5345 2.33 Ghz Quad Core Processor - qty 2
- 24GB 1333 Mhz ECC Ram
- 500GB Western Digital Caviar Black
- XFX
  nVidia Quadro
- Intel Pro 4 port NIC - qty 2

Comment: Which Windows 7 Edition do you use? Not all Editions support 2 CPUs. Why don't you use a real Server OS?

Comment: The description of Classpnp.sys is `SCSI Class System DLL`.